# Rebuild html form with ajax post

Tags: html, ajax, forms, submit

I try to replace html form which allows to change the language of the website with a ajax post. The form submits data, just the value of the chosen language, per POST-method and then I set this value in via php in a Session-Variable.

The HTML-Code:

```
<form target="_self" method="post" action="Home.php">
<button type="submit" name="language" value="deutsch"> <img src="Germany.png" /></button>
<button type="submit" name="language" value="englisch"> <img src="USA.png" /></button>
</form>
```

And the PHP-Code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['language']))
{$_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
};
if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])){
$_SESSION['language'] = 'deutsch';}
if($_SESSION['language'] == 'deutsch')
{require('../deutsch.php');
}
elseif($_SESSION['language'] == 'englisch')
{require('../englisch.php');
}
```

The code above is working fine and the language is changing by a click on the image.
Now I try to use a ajax post as onclick function on the image. The function fires, but I don't know how to write the ajax post. I tried:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "window.location.pathname",
    data: "language=deutsch",
    });
```

But the language is not chanching. Where is my mistake? PHP-Code should be the same I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main issues here:

- request path is wrong. The URL should be `window.location.pathname` (without quotes).
- you haven't initialized session; see docs for `session_start()`
- although you can send a POST request to some PHP file which will set session variable, you cannot re-run your PHP code (and include relevant files) without reloading the page, as PHP is server-side.

Therefore, you cannot change language with AJAX request this way. Possible solution is to move PHP code to another file, and return its output as AJAX response:

```
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: window.location.pathname,
         data: "language=deutsch",
         success: function(data) {  // data is response from PHP file
              alert(data);          // you can do whatever you want with it
         }
    });
```

This is possible (I mean: *works*), but not really clean or efficient. 
Stick to synchronous requests or/and take look at some frameworks that provide translation solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is working and data gives me the right response data. I've forgotten to write the session initialization down here, but it's in my code. And yeah, there should be no quotes around the URL. Maybe I really should stick to synchronous requests - the page reload is no problem.